# Cloned Select Element doesn't post its when submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the form that contains a table, I also have a button that lets the user add a row by cloning the first row. This is the code:

HTML

```
    <button onclick="insertRow()">Add Row</button>
    <form action="save.php" method="post">
<table class="mod_table" id="mod_table">
            <thead>
            <th>ID No.</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>M.I.</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Contact No.</th>
        </thead>
            <tr id="mod_table_row">
                <td><input type="text" name="id_num[]" size="8" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lname[]" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname[]" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mname[]" size="1" required></td>
                <td><select name="course[]" style="padding: 2px;">
                    <?php $opt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblcourses");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($opt)){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['course_code'] ?>"><?php echo $row['abbr'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address[]" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="contact[]" size="11" required></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<button>save</button>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function insertRow(){
var row = document.getElementById('mod_table_row');
var table = document.getElementById('mod_table');
var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);

table.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

My problem is that when i submit the form, it only post the selected value of the original select element and the selected values of the clones are not posted. All other inputs works well, only the select element doesn't work. Why? Can anyone help?

Here's the php code:

```
<?php 
include '../dbcon.php';

$lim = $_POST['id_num'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$first = $_POST['fname'];
$mid = $_POST['mname'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$addr = $_POST['address'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($lim); $i++ ){

    $id=$lim[$i];
    $lname =$lastname[$i];
    $fname = $first[$i];
    $mname = $mid[$i];
    $course = $course[$i];
    $add = $addr[$i];
    $cont = $contact[$i];


    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tblstudent(id,lname,fname,mname,contact,address,course) VALUES ('$id','$lname','$fname','$mname','$cont','$add','$course')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
if($query == true){
    echo 'saved';
}
else{
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: If you do a vardump of $_POST what do you see? Since your form names include [] the post variables should be coming back to you as arrays. You'll need to loop through the arrays to get the individual values.

Comment: @Raimonds There are no events on the first element. The event is on the `form`. The cloned elements contain server-side code, which won't run because the page has already been delivered to the client.

Comment: You can't clone serverside code, just the final output.

Comment: @Raimonds You *can* clone server-side code, it just won't execute.

Comment: No you can't dont mix javascript frontend and actual backend of php. you do realize that response you get from server is already rendered to client and contains no server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Your array identifier should be at start
[]fname
[]lname

this would actually create array of object in post
I believe this is what you want.

I used this tool to test if my assumptions are correct regards array identifiers 
http://phpfiddle.org

this is sample code

```
<form method=post>
<select name=same[]>
<option>1<option>
<option>2<option>
</select>
<select name=same[]>
<option>1<option>
<option>2<option>
</select>

<input type=submit value=ok>
</form>

<?php 
echo var_dump($_POST["same"]);
?>
```

p.s
if you want to submit array of object you need to use objectName[].prop as a name of input field.

Comment: Actually, my problem is not about the array identifier or the names of the inputs,because they already work fine. The problem is with the select element.

Comment: if you look at my sample code it works fine, it should be the same as yours, only issue I had when fiddling was that if I would want to receive array of persons with their respective data was that without specifying object name my post data was empty.
are you sure you want to receive array of names, array of surnames, array of middle names, not the actual array of people?

You could also use fiddler to see data is being sent in request.

Answer (score 0):

The puzzling thing is I've tested your code quickly in a pen and it works fine. I've added a couple of courses to the select, to replace the query, and set the form action to a simple PHP file that I have that prints back everything it receives. All selected courses in the cloned rows came through fine in an array, as you would expect.

So I think that the problem you have may come from some of the courses not having a value. Could you please post the generated HTML with the option elements?

On a side note, make sure you sanitize the input in your PHP before saving it to your database. This is a huge security fault.

Comment: Yes, it work fine if you do that. But I needed the query because I am not sure what are the courses, therefore, it must be generated with the query, but it turns out that its not possible that way.

Comment: @Rouge its if fine to generate those like it is, unless it dosn't generate it properly. Keep in mind that php runs before you get html as a response from server.

Comment: yeah, i got it. php runs when the page loads. once its loaded php don't run anymore :)

Answer (score -1):

When form data is submitted, each form field that has a `name` will submit its `value`. Since you are cloning the first row, all the subsequent rows wind up with elements that are exact duplicates of the first, meaning you have multiple elements with the same `name`. You'll need to ensure that each new element gets its own unique `name`.

Additionally, the cloning operation happens client-side, but the cloned element contains server-side code (the PHP). The only way that PHP will run is if it is present in the document prior to the server sending the document to the client.  You'll need to replace that PHP with AJAX calls to get an already rendered page to update with new server content or you could make your clone code go to the server and request a new page with an additional row that is created server-side.

Comment: This is wrong assumption, for php it should create array of that type.
However in .NET it needs strict number sequence in order to work.
p.s
I was too harsh to down vote, so I changed my mind.

Comment: @Raimonds I have no idea what you are referring to. This is a simple matter of expecting server-side code to run after the page has been delivered to the client.

Comment: Yes, I know that they are duplicates that is why I put [] on the names to make them arrays. Btw, i don't know anything about the down vote.

Comment: @Rouge They are not arrays. The `name` attribute holds only string data.

Comment: @Scott Marcus is AJAX the only way I can achieve my goal?

Comment: @Rouge I just updated my answer with the only other option, which would be to make the clone code call another PHP page and have that PHP (which is running on the server) deliver a new page with a new row that contains the information you need. In short, server-side code needs to run server-side.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought they're arrays cause they're treated like that when I post it.

Comment: I would assume this would affect all fields, but as OP points out 'All other inputs works well, only the select element doesn't work.'

Comment: Thanks I'll try it.

Comment: To the HTML parser `id_num[]` is just a string and if you have two elements with that same `name` there will be problems. HTML has only one data format --- strings.